# Stackoverflow tag confusion

Tags: discussion

I noticed that there's 14 instances of a [stackoverflow](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stackoverflow) tag. This tag is easy to confuse the site with the actual issue. How do we rectify this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given that a question about Stack Overflow (the site) would likely be off topic and hence closed and then deleted I don't think we need to distinguish.

Having a specific [stack-overflow-the-site](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stack-overflow-the-site) tag might appear to legitimise such questions.

Comment: Good enough for me